# Why prefix sql function names?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, naming-conventions

What is a scenario that exemplifies a good reason to use prefixes, such as fn_GetName, on function names in SQL Server?  It would seem that it would be unnecessary since usually the context of its usage would make it clear that it's a function.  I have not used any other language that has ever needed prefixes on functions, and I can't think of a good scenario that would show why SQL is any different.

My only thinking is that perhaps in older IDE's it was useful for grouping functions together when the database objects were all listed together, but modern IDE's already make it clear what is a function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are correct about older IDEs

As a DBA, trying to fix permissions using SQL Server Enterprise Manager (SQL Server 2000 and 7.0), it was complete bugger trying to view permissions. If you had ufn or usp or vw it became easier to group things together because of how the GUI presented the data.

Saying that, if you have `SELECT * FROM Thing`, what is Thing? A view or a table? It may work for you as a developer but it will crash when deployed because you don't grant permissions on the table itself: only views or procs. Surely a `vwThing` will keep your blood pressure down...?

If you use schemas, it becomes irrelevant. You can "namespace" your objects. For example, tables in "Data" and other objects per client in other schemas eg `WebGUI`

Edit:

Function. You have table valued and scalar functions. If you stick with the code "VerbNoun" concept, how do you know which is which without some other clue. (of course, this can't happen because object names are unique)

```
SELECT dbo.GetName() FROM MyTable
SELECT * FROM dbo.GetName()
```

If you use a plural to signify a table valued function, this is arguably worse

```
SELECT dbo.GetName() FROM MyTable
SELECT * FROM dbo.GetNames()
```

Whereas this is less ambiguous, albeit offensive to some folk ;-)

```
SELECT dbo.sfnGetName() FROM MyTable
SELECT * FROM dbo.tfnGetName()
```

With schemas. And no name ambiguity.

```
SELECT ScalarFN.GetName() FROM MyTable
SELECT * FROM TableFN.GetName()
```

Your "any other language" comment doesn't apply. SQL isn't structured like c#, Java, f#, Ada (OK, PL/SQL might be), VBA, whatever: there is no object or namespace hierarchy. No `Object.DoStuff` method stuff.

A prefix may be just the thing to keep you sane...

Comment: Yes, I agree on views it is useful.  I am asking specifically about functions though.  Thanks.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of even languages like C, where you might have a function that is not attached to an object, it still is clearly a function from the context of usage.  But anyhow, good point regarding table-valued vs scalar-valued, which means that a single fn_ prefix alone accomplishes little, what is really needed, if that scenario is a concern, is two different prefixes as you demonstrated.

Comment: @AaronLS: C could be an example too. SQL isn't like most client languages and "conventional" assumptions may not apply. I'm not saying it makes sense or is good, but it's useful just to keep track of your code. We use a schemas for all functions FWIW. We separate functions by their verbs. "Calc"= scalar, "Get" = table etc

Comment: I think all you're points have an analogy to C.  In C you would use verbs like Get/Calc to convey semantics, prefixes may indicate that the functions all dealt with a particular struct, or were part of a particular library.  But you would not add a prefix of func_ or fn_ simply to indicate that it was a function, and as yet I have not seen any reason in SQL to add a prefix completely across the board such as fn_ which does nothing but indicate that a function is a function.  Anyhow, marking this as the answer as it has good examples that people should consider regarding function prefixes.

Comment: @AaronLS: Thank you. We don't use prefixes, but we do use schemas/verbs instead. Functions are quite the odd one out in SQL Server so I can see why you asked.

Answer (score 7):

There's no need to prefix function names with `fn_` any more than there's a need to prefix table names with `t_` (a convention I have seen).  This sort of systematic prefix tends to be used by people who are not yet comfortable with the language and who need the convention as an extra help to understanding the code.

Answer (score 7):

Like all naming conventions, it hardly matters what the convention actually is. What really matter is to be **consistent**. So even if the convention is wrong, it is still important to stick to it for consistency. Yes, it may be argued that if the naming convention is wrong then it should be changed, but the effort implies a lot: rename *all* objects, change source code, all maintenance procedures, get the dev team committed to follow the new convention, have all the support and ops personnel follow the new rules etc etc. On a large org, the effort to change a well established naming convention is just simply overwhelming.

I don't know what your situation is, but you should consider carefully before proposing a naming convention change just for sake of 'pretty'. No matter how bad the existing naming convention in your org is, is far better to stick to it and keep the naming consistency than to ignore it and start your own.

Of course, more often than not, the naming convention is not only bad, is also not followed and names *are* inconsistent. In that case, sucks to be you...

Answer (score 5):

> What is a scenario that exemplifies a
>   good reason to use prefixes

THere is none. People do all kind of stuff because they always did so, and quite a number of bad habits are explained with ancient knowledge that is wrong for many years.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of prefixes, but perhaps one advantage could be that these `fn_` prefixes might make it easier to identify that a particular function is user-defined, rather than in-built.

Comment: No you recognize the scalar UDFs because they have to been used with explicit schema reference (mostly dbo.)

Comment: @bernd_k: You have a point there, but in other DBMSes, that is not always the case... So prefixing could make that distinction clearer in databases other than SQL Server.

Comment: I think all DBMS are giving us so few functions, that we can easily remenber the few.

Answer (score 2):

We had many painful meetings at our company about this. IMO, we don't need prefixes on any object names. However, you could make an argument for putting them on views, if the name of the view might conflict with the underlying table name.

In any case, there is no SQL requirement that prefixes be used, and frankly, IMO, they have no real value.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noticed, any scenario you define can easily be challenged, so there's no rule defining it as necessary; however, there's equally no rule saying it's unnecessary, either.  Like all naming conventions, it's more important to have consistent usage rather than justification.

Comment: I agree on consistent usage, but I don't want to advocate not using fn_ and then later find that there are cases where that will be a big disadvantage, so I am asking for those examples that "easily challange" my opinion :)

Comment: I don't think that there will be; any argument presented for a specific naming convention boils down to identifying the source of the data (e.g., views and functions can have some sort of logic affecting output as opposed to tables), and those arguments can be battled back and forth without any real resolution.  Pick one and move forward; if you have a dev team that likes prefixes for functions and views (to distinguish them from tables), use them.

Answer (score 1):

One (and the only) advantage I can think of is that it a consequently applied prefixing scheme could make using intellisense / autocomplete easier since related functionality is automagically grouped together.

Comment: I would say the opposite is true

Answer (score 1):

Since I recently stumbled over this question, I'd like to add the following point in favour of prefixes: Imagine, you have some object id from some system table and you want to determine whether it's a function, proc, view etc. You could of course run a test for each type, it's much easier though to extract the prefix from the object name and then act upon that. This gets even easier when you use an underscore to separate the prefix from the name, e.g. usp_Foo instead of uspFoo. IMHO it's not just about stupid IDEs.